# Unable to view nginx a cached static webpage on nginx

Tags: nginx, tomcat, caching, runtime-error, reverse-proxy

I wish to view a cached static webpage on nginx through this URL:

http://localhost:8087/mycache/welcome_page.html

The welcome_page.html is kept in this location on Windows:

C:\nginx-1.22.1\html\welcome_page.html

The tricky part is that I have a reverse proxy setup using `upstream` with backend tomcat servers.

Despite specifying the location block for `mycache` the request goes to backend tomcat and thus fails with error `the page you are looking for is currently unavailable.` instead of looking for the cache HTML file on nginx.

[image]

```
An error occurred.
Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable.
Please try again later.

If you are the system administrator of this resource then you should check the error log for details.

Faithfully yours, nginx.
```

Below is my nginx configuration:

Can you please suggest how can i fix the problem?

http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;
sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout  65;

```
upstream tomcatcluster {
        server 127.0.0.1:8181;
        server 127.0.0.1:8282;
        }
        

server {
    listen       8087;
    server_name  localhost;

            location /mycache/ {
    
            root C:\nginx-1.22.1\html;  
            index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    

    location / {
    
            proxy_pass http://tomcatcluster;
            
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

}
```

Can you please suggest how can we get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

If you are manually adding the pages to `C:\nginx-1.22.1\html`, remove the `proxy_pass` line from the `location /mycache/`

```
location /mycache/ {
  root C:\nginx-1.22.1\html;
  index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

Otherwise, let me know if what your are trying to achieve is to set the [`proxy_temp_path`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_temp_path)

Comment: i still get the 404 error `404 Not Found`